# Running wsgi application using socketio python library and liighttpd

Tags: python, socket.io, lighttpd

I am using [python socket io library](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html) for using the web socket feature. I instantiated a  WSGI application using the socket io library:

```
import  socketio

static_files = {
    '/': './public/index.html',
}

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()

app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files=static_files)

print("Server start..")

@sio.on('message')
async def print_message(sid, message):
    print("Socket ID: " , sid)
```

I want to run the WSGI application using [lighttpd server](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/). I am not sure how to achieve this. How can I run the my WSGI application with lighttpd to serve static content(s)? (I am on a Ubuntu machine)

Comment: lighttpd.net (the site to which you linked above) has documentation to help you.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI

Comment: I can't tell how to use it with socket io library from the documentation

Comment: https://github.com/greyli/python-socketio